# How to remove parameters from URL when using T4MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, t4mvc

Action method looks like

```
public virtual ActionResult Show(int productId, bool isValid, bool getByStoreId = false)
```

When I call this action I get url like

```
.../Product/Show/221?isValid=True&getByStoreId=True
```

But I want to display just

```
.../Product/Show/221
```

Does T4MVC has some shortcut for this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "ProductsShow_Default",
                "Product/{action}/{articleId}",
                MVC.Product.Show()
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, any parameters that you put in the `RouteValueDictionary` for a link that are not contained in any route will by default be added to the query string. Your only way around not putting them in the query string is mapping a route for them, but they're still going to be displayed in the URL.

Comment: So if I understand correct if I need action that requires 4 parameters but I want to display only 2 in url the best solution is to find a way to use that action with 2 parameters instead 4 because all parameters from action method must be part of url?

Comment: Yes correct, *although* if you're finding yourself sending more and more parameters to a controller, you should think about your design. Ask yourself, is there any other way I can get this data *without* having to send it all to an action? If it's a post request, you should really be sending a model back to the action with all the fields that you need contained within the model :)